# vba enums error: "Invalid inside procedure."

Tags: vba, excel, enums, runtime-error

I am trying to loop through some cells in EXcel via VBA. I want to use Enums in it, but while running code compiler error appears i.e.: "Invalid inside procedure."

Following is the code snippet:

```
Dim resSub(1 To 8) As Integer

Private Enum Subjects
    Hindi = 1
    English = 2
    Sanskrit = 3
    Math = 4
    Science = 5
    SoScience = 8
End Enum

Dim resCur As Integer
resCur = 0
Dim resG As Integer
resG = 0
Dim resF As Integer
resF = 0
Dim markG As Integer
markG = 0

For j = Hindi To SoScience
    resCur = Sheets("Result").Cells(pst_end_row, ColumnAZ(cpy_start_col + 6 + 2 * j)).Value
    If (resCur < 33) And Not (j = Science) Then
            resSub(j) = 1
            resG = resG + 1
            If (resCur >= 27) Then
                markG = markG + 33 - resCur
            Else
                resF = resF + 1
            End If
    ElseIf (resCur < 25) And (j = Science) Then
            resSub(j) = 1
            resG = resG + 1
            If (resCur >= 19) Then
                markG = markG + 25 - resCur
            Else
                resF = resF + 1
            End If
    End If
Next j
```

Could someone please help me over this as I am new to VBA coding?

Thanks,
AJ

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
Where there is a shell, there is a way. ;)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Is the error pointing to a specific line in your code?  My first thought would be to (temporarily, at least) turn the ENUMs into constants -- so that you're then using "for j = 1 to 8" directly, rather than messing with any conversion to/from the enumerated values.

Comment: Yes it points to "Private Enum Subjects". Actually I wanted to jump 5 to 8 directly instead of ignoring 6 and 7. I think there must be some way. But for now I can try that as well. :) Thanks Ralph

Comment: You Enum isn't inside your sub/function is it?

Comment: Hi Nick, Enum is defined inside button click function. I have pasted just the code snippets. It is defined inside Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(). Thanks I tried defining it outside function and it worked. :)

Answer (score 5):

Declare the ENUM ***outside of*** the procedure -- not within it.

Comment: @Decentdevill2 Wanna mark it as the best answer for your case?

Answer (score 0):

What language do you usually use? Doesn't seem to mesh with VBA well.

You could use a dictionary instead of an enum?

```
Dim Subjects As Object:Set Subjects = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Subjects.Add "Hindi", 1
Subjects.Add "English", 2
Subjects.Add "Sanskirt", 3
Subjects.Add "Math", 4
Subjects.Add "Science", 5
Subjects.Add "SoScience", 8

Dim Key As Variant
Dim Value As Integer

For Each Key In Subjects.Keys

    Value = Subjects(Key)
    ' Key == "Hindi" -> Value == 1  

Next Key
```

Comment: Yes, I am a C programmer from years. Dictionary also seems a good way to implement same. I will try this out. Thanks.